# How to catch platformException in flutter/dart?

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting

```
Exception has occurred.

PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_canceled,
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12501: , null))
```

whenever I try to cancel login with google pop up in my app.

**STEP TO REPRODUCE:**

In the app when pressed login with google button the google sign in page appears with all the gmail accounts to choose from to login or signup.

Touch the outer area of the pop up to cancel the sign in , which then shuts down the pop up.

After that there is platform exception in the code saying :

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_canceled,
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12501: , null))
```

Now the login button is not working and the app crashes,

Tried try/catch - not working

Comment: Please add the code you have showing what you are doing. Are you using await in the api call ?

Comment: I am having this same issue

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
try {
  final res = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  if (res != null) loggedUser = res.user;
} on PlatformException catch (err) {
  // Handle err
} catch (err) {
  // other types of Exceptions
}
```

Comment: It is usually useful to include some explanation of how the code answers the question or solves the issue.

Comment: My mistake was to not call `await`. If you don't call the await in the try then the error will raise after you finished the block and thus wont be caught in the `on` or `catch` block.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, this issue is still not fixed and it does not occur if you run the flutter app from the terminal using `flutter run -d`
Don't worry about the release version of your application. It does not crashes or freezes in the release version.

Answer (score 1):

I have also recently faced this error and, I have found out that the `.catchError()` callback wasn't being called in the debug mode (which is when you click the `Run->Start Debugging` button in VSCode).

However, when you type in flutter run -d , then, the `.catchError()` method gets called back as it is not in debug mode.

To get your preferred simulator's code paste this line of code in the terminal:

```
instruments -s devices
```

If that doesn't work, you can also try pasting this:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

The  `.catchError()` method will get called unlike before and the code inside that will get executed as expected!

Additionally, the app won't crash anymore with a `PlatformException()` and instead you will get a log like this one:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

I have been facing this problem in Google Sign In too, in which the `.catchError()` was not being called!

In conclusion, if you have some error with handling errors in Firebase Authentication, you should first try to first run in through the terminal. Thanks, and I hope this helps and trust me, it should work for you!

Answer (score 1):

***This is how you can catch platform exception***

```
try {
  //
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == '???') {
     // 
  }
} catch (e) {
  //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PlatformException: Thrown to indicate that a platform interaction failed in the platform plugin. (null safety)

I was facing a similar issue. Adding the services import solved it. [Check the docs for more information.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/services-library.html)

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with SignIn with google. User cancel operation or internet problem. I have Searched a lot and tried a lot of Exception catch solutions. but in the end, I found something Helpful and decide to share it here.

**Just try to *run your project without debugging mode*.**

Answer (score 0):

the try-catch block can be used to catch exceptions that might occur in your code, including PlatformException in Flutter/Dart. The provided code uses this block to handle exceptions that might occur during the Google sign-in process:

```
signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
        try {
          final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser =
          await GoogleSignIn(scopes: <String>['email']).signIn();
          if (googleUser != null) {
            final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
            await googleUser.authentication;
            final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
                idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken);
            try{
              await FirebaseAuth.instance
                .signInWithCredential(credential);
            } on FirebaseAuthException catch(e){
              print("********${e.message}*********");
            }
          }
        } on PlatformException catch (e) {
          print("********${e.message}*********");
        }
      }
```

In the case of a PlatformException, the code prints the exception message to the console.

```
output:
********com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 7: *********
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Summary of my observations:

(1) As others have stated, the exception is correctly caught by the try-catch block in Release mode. But in Debug mode, the try catch has no effect and the program crashes.
This is my test code, running on a physical Android (API 31) device:

```
  void _login() async {
    try {
      await _firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: _email, password: _passwd);
      print('You are now logged in.');
    } on PlatformException catch (pex) {
      print('This block is never reached in debug mode');
      print(pex.toString());
    } catch (ex) {
      print(ex.toString());
    }
  }
```

(2) To trigger the exception, it is enough if you leave the email and password fields blank and submit. The underlying stack trace correctly catches this:

```
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.firebase_auth_platform_interface.FirebaseAuthHostApi.signInWithEmaiFailed to handle message
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.firebase_auth_platform_interface.FirebaseAuthHostApi.signInWithEmaijava.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given String is empty or null
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.firebase_auth_platform_interface.FirebaseAuthHostApi.signInWithEmai    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkNotEmpty(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@18.1.0:2)
E/BasicMessageChannel#dev.flutter.pigeon.firebase_auth_platform_interface.FirebaseAuthHostApi.signInWithEmai    at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@22.2.0:161)
```

(3) Same issue happens if you enter an invalid email id or the wrong credentials. On every occasion, FirebaseAuth seems to catch the problem correctly - but when the exception bubbles up, it ends up as an 'internal error':

```
E/RecaptchaCallWrapper(29181): Initial task failed for action RecaptchaAction(action=signInWithPassword)with exception - An internal error has occurred. [ INVALID_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS ]
```

It does seem that there is a platform bug to be fixed here.