# Flutter: Camera keeps stopping error on image_picker package

Tags: flutter

I am using the [image_picker](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker) package to work with camera but the app crashes whenever I trigger the pick image from camera. The error I get is `Camera keeps stopping`

The code I am using is

```
Future<void> _takePicture() async {
    final imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.camera,
      maxWidth: 600,
    );
}
```

I am calling this function on a button click. This is what I get in the debug console:

```
D/FlutterView(24995): Detaching from a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@5a82446
D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate(24995): Detaching FlutterEngine from the Activity that owns this Fragment.
D/FlutterEngine(24995): Destroying.
D/FlutterEnginePluginRegistry(24995): Destroying.
```

Comment: are you sure flutter is updated to last Version ?

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja Yes I am using the latest version of Flutter.

Comment: ok plaese add try and catch on your code and check what Error code if throw exception

Comment: show this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56080818/how-to-catch-platformexception-in-flutter-dart)  to know how catch it 

inside catch print the error code

Comment: @MahmoudAbuElheja Tried using try catch as well, no error is getting printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to the emulator. Don't know what it was though but I ran the app on a newly created emulator and the camera worked.